# Amazon Connect Instance Logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

How do I enable AWS Amazon connect logging?
I have enabled the logs in the instance and I can see the log groups in ClouldWatch but no logs are being created.

[image: Instance with Logging enabled]

[image: CloudWatch with Log group created]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to AWS Document

> Logs are generated only for contact flows that include a Set Logging Behavior block with logging set to enabled.
>
> When you use a Set logging behavior block to enable or disable logging
> for a flow, logging is also enabled or disabled for any subsequent
> flow that a contact is transferred to, even if the flow does not
> include a Set logging behavior block. To avoid logging that persists
> between flows, enable or disable a Set logging behavior block as
> needed for that specific flow.
>
> To enable or disable contact flow logs for a contact flow
>
> Add a Set Logging Behavior block and connect it to another block in
> the flow.
>
> Open the properties for the block. Choose Enable or Disable.
>
> Choose Save.
>
> If you add a Set logging behavior block to a contact flow that is
> already published, you must publish it again to start generating logs
> for it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the instance parameter must also be set to on